# Why does my $q.all's .then get called instantly?

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a function that kicks off 10 "data reads" and returns a promise that is (supposed) to be resolved when all data reads complete.  However, what seems to be happening is that the #q.all(...) thinks the data reads' promises are instantly resolved when they are not.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LHpNQ/).  Click the button 3 times to kick off the data reads.  They are supposed to finish 5 seconds later.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout, $q) {
    $scope.a = 0;
    $scope.c = "";
    $scope.d = "";

    $scope.click = function click() {
        $scope.a++;
        if ($scope.a == 3) $scope.read();
    };

    $scope.read = function read() {
        $scope.readData()
            .then(function (a) {
                    a.forEach(function(b) {
                        $scope.c += b;
                    });
                    $scope.c += ". done.";
            });
        $scope.c = "Data read started...";
    };

    $scope.readData = function readData() {
        var res = "";
        var ps = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ps.push($q.defer());
        }

        ps.forEach(function(aq, i) {
            $timeout(
                function () {
                    aq.resolve("(data "+i+")");
                    }, 5000);
        }); 

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $q.all(ps)
            .then(function(results) {
                deferred.resolve(results);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    function log(s) {
        $scope.d += "/"+s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't pushing promises into `ps` array rather you are pushing the whole deferred object

try

```
ps.push($q.defer().promise);
```

Comment: That'll do it.  I corrected the fiddle.  Thank you.

Comment: It is maybe interesting to note that jQuery's `.when()` doesn't differentiate between deferreds and promises. You can pass either to it. I'm surprised that angular's `$q.all()` (and presumably `Q.all()`) isn't similarly tolerant.